# Node.js / Require of the same NPM for diffrent purpose

Tags: linux, node.js

I have the following require in `main.js`

```
var s3 = require('s3');
var s3Big = new require('s3');
```

and the following variables:

```
var client = s3.createClient({
                    maxAsyncS3: 20,
                    s3RetryCount: 10,
                    s3RetryDelay: 10000,
                    multipartUploadThreshold: 209715200,
                    multipartUploadSize: 209715200,
                    s3Options: {
                      accessKeyId: accessKeyIdParam,
                      secretAccessKey: secretAccessIdParam,
                    },
             });

var clientBig = s3Big.createClient({
                    maxAsyncS3: 25,
                    s3RetryCount: 10,
                    s3RetryDelay: 10000,
                    multipartUploadThreshold: 209715200,
                    multipartUploadSize: 209715200,
                    s3Options: {
                      accessKeyId: accessKeyIdParam,
                      secretAccessKey: secretAccessIdParam,
                    },
                  });
```

When I upload a file greater then 10GB, I use the `clientBig`:

```
if (file.stats.size > 10000000000) {
  clientBig.uploadFile(params);
} else {
  client.uploadFile(params);
}
```

The problem is that if I have for example 2 files of 15GB and 1000 files of 4KB, I notice that there is a significant delay with the upload of the small files. This despite the fact that two diffrents instnaces of `s3` are responsible for this uploading.

I also check if its related to the number of connections on this specific machine. I found that when I upload the small files from diffrent `.js` script, then there is no delay. So it doesn't relate to limitations of the machine.

How can I avoid it so the small files will be uploaded, without that are affected from the uploading process of the big files?

Comment: It makes no sense doing a second `require`, they will both return the same object anyway, it's the `createClient` which will (should?) return different objects, each with their own parameters. But they make share common queues etc.

Comment: Where did you read that by doing so you're getting different instances of the module? Modules get cached the first time that they are required, any subsequent request will return the cached module.

Comment: @jcaron So there is no way (in node.js) to do some priority to the small files?

Comment: @cviejo So there is no way (in node.js) to do some priority to the small files?

Comment: I think the question is more whether such option exists in the `s3` module, you should check there

Comment: Well, in that case, if you are getting the two files to upload at the same time, you should queue the uploads, upload the small file first and do the uploads sequentially, not in parallel.

Comment: @cviejo If I will call to external file, which will upload this file (In this file I will require `s3`), should it works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102264/discussion-between-cviejo-and-middleware).